# How to convert all images in one folder to numpy files?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to do Semantic image segmentation based on Unet.

I have to work with Pascal VOC 2012 dataset, however I don't know how to do it, do I manually select images for the train & val and convert them into numpy and then load them into the model? Or is there another way?

If this is the first one I would like to know how to convert all the images present in a folder into .npy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood correctly, you just need to go through all the files from the folder and add them to the numpy table?

```
numpyArrays = [yourfunc(file_name) for file_name in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, file_name))]
```

yourfunc is the function you need to write to convert one file from dataset format to numpy table